# M Function to trim specific range

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot, m

I need to trim in Power Query a column that has the following structure:

- "ABC (XI 011)"
- "ABC (XI1 02)"

I need to trim/ get every value between "(" and " ".
And I need to trim/ get every value between " " and ")".
For the 2 examples above the result should be for the first column:

- XI
- XI1

And for the second column:

- 011
- 02

Is there any chance to get this result with Power Query functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use such code:

```
let
    Source = #table({"col"},{{"ABC (XI 011)"}, {"ABC (XI1 02)"}}),
    split = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "col", (x)=>Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(x, "(", ")")," "))
in
    split
```